# How can I disable the use of minibuffer in lsp-ui?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp-ui

When lsp-ui-doc offers me information about the symbol at point, it does that in a hover window (good) *and* in the minibuffer (bad).

I've found no mention of the minibuffer in the customisations of lsp-*

Can you please tell me where/how to disable the use of the minibuffer in lsp-ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not related to lsp-ui. I do not have lsp-ui installed and still got annoying previews in the minibuffer in lsp-latex. Turning off eldoc-mode has solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

As @sergolala hints, this is eldoc related, but turning off eldoc is not the answer.

Instead, see the customizable variable [`lsp-eldoc-render-all`](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/mode/#lsp-eldoc-render-all).  There is some discussion of this variable on github issues ([Setting lsp-eldoc-render-all to nil can still show multi-line text](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/443), [lsp-mode doesn't display signatures in Rust when lsp-eldoc-render-all is nil](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/2613)), but the documentation for the variable reads:

> Display all of the info returned by document/onHover. If this is set to nil, eldoc will show only the symbol information.

However, you may want to just set [`lsp-eldoc-enable-hover`](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/settings/mode/#lsp-eldoc-enable-hover) to `nil`:

> If non-nil, eldoc will display hover info when it is present.